# How to download a dropbox file to web application using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropbox

I am working on an web application using angularjs. I have a pdf file in drop box. I need to show the content of this pdf file in my web application. I have the URL of this pdf file. 
How to show the content of this pdf file using the URL in my angular application? I need to show the content of this pdf file in the same web page as my application.
Should I do the authentication before downloading a file from drop box.?  What API should I use to download a pdf file from drop box?
Please explain me in details how to go about it?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: My Angular application will get the URL of the dropbox where data.pdf is stored in dropbox. Say I have a URL like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/key123124235/data.pdf?dl=0. Now I need to use this URL in my application and show the pdf content in my web application. For doing this should I  use dropbox API to download the pdf file from dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) or is there any other way of downloading this pdf file and showing it's content in my web application?. I hope this is clear

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you're going to do with the content, but hopefully https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 helps you to convert the link you have into one directly to the content. (Replace `dl=0` with `raw=1`.)